# Filter service in angularjs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I am rewriting an app that uses html, js and php into angular with rest php. I came across an issues regarding filters. In the actual form i have dropdowns that are populated ajax by js from php. The config in the js is made something like

```
form = new form('user-page');
form.ajaxselects = [ ['UserID', {table: 'users', DefaultValue: 5} ] ]
form.construct();

function form(formName) {
var this.ajaxselects;
function construct() {
   foreach (this.ajaxselects as ajaxselect) {
      $.post( ajaxselect[0], { Action:'get' },
       function( data ) {
          // exemplification, not real code
          $(this).select(ajaxselect[0]).values = data;
       }, 'json'
     );
   }
}
```

EDIT:

How it currently works with js:

I instantiate an object, called form and in that form i configure all my elements. Dropdowns, field validations etc.

After i configure (the configuration means that i say for a dropdown where to take the value from the server, what is the default value etc), for a validation i say what's the rule (it's mandatory, it's decimal).

And then when i run a function on the form object i go for each dropdown and populate it, add events validate the inputs etc.

I would like to know if i can and if yes, how, to build something like this in angular. To give to a service let's say a set of rules, something like:
['user_id', http_request:'server.com/api/populate/user_id', default_Value:1] and then i get the dropdown for users populated with the values. I don't know how to explain it better.

Comment: We really don't know what that code does or what you are trying to do with filters. Show some context how you use what is shown and explain filter issue in more detail.

Comment: Sounds like you need a directive or multiple directives

Comment: I have a list and i want to show in the list only the values that correspond to a certain user for example. The code is just an example. bassically, the code goes to ajaxselects array, and in a foreach makes and ajax call to server.com/filters with that parameters and gets a response and fills in the options of the dropdown

Comment: Still not clear what specific problem is. Can use service to manage array data

Comment: I have a list and i want to filter it by customer let's say. I have a lot of filters like this which are populated from the server. What should i use in angular to deal with them ? Service, directive? Have any examples?

Comment: Still asking far too general a question. Sounds like you really need to go through an angular tutorial like the one in documentation site

Comment: @charlietfl How can i be more specific? :)

Comment: By providing code samples of use cases or creating a demo that represents problem